# WIX illegal character in path

Tags: wix

I have error

> Illegal character in path

when i try to build my WIX.Setup. I could locate the the problem at following components

```
  <Component Id="C.Cef.Common.BrowserSubprocess.Core" Guid="{5603fa71-5739-4513-9cba-793a6f6d29ce}">
    <File Id="CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll"    Source="$(var.Path.Cefsharp.Commonx64)\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="C.Cef.Common.BrowserSubprocessexe" Guid="{5b0b77cd-7787-4c8a-b388-8042d179a788}">
    <File Id="CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"       Source="$(var.Path.Cefsharp.Commonx64)\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="C.Cef.Common.Core"                 Guid="{98a016a2-50cb-4fdb-ae50-46f7f35ac270}">
    <File Id="CefSharp.Core.dll"                    Source="$(var.Path.Cefsharp.Commonx64)\CefSharp.Core.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="C.Cef.Common.CefSharp"             Guid="{a181bbed-fc28-41c8-868d-8c1dd62dbc46}">
    <File Id="CefSharp.dll"                         Source="$(var.Path.Cefsharp.Commonx64)\CefSharp.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
```

If I remove them it is working.

```
  <?define Path.Cefsharp.Commonx64 =              "$(var.Path.Packages)\CefSharp.Common.55.0.0\CefSharp\x64 ?>
```

Where is the illegal character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quotes are only a sometimes-required syntax for the value in a [preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html) define.

Since you are missing the trailing quote that you must have intended, the leading one is considered to be part of the value!

```
<?define Path.Cefsharp.Commonx64 = 
  "$(var.Path.Packages)\CefSharp.Common.55.0.0\CefSharp\x64 ?>
```

I used the `candle -p` switch to find this out.

Comment: Thank you so much - its my first time setting up the complete `WIX` stuff - was looking for something like `candle -p`

Comment: Even if you use MSBuild or Visual Studio on top fo that, the WiX command-line tools are what's being called. (You can crank up the log verbosity in MSBuild or VS, if you like.) Be sure to check out the [WiX Toolset diagram](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/chm/files/content/WiX_Toolset_Diagram.png) (that's a link to the source; it seems to be broken in the website version of the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have terribly much experience with WIX syntax, but [according to the documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/specifying_source_files.html) the File element needs an exclamation point when identifying payload via named binder paths:

```
<Component Id="C.Cef.Common.BrowserSubprocess.Core" Guid="{5603fa71-5739-4513-9cba-793a6f6d29ce}">
    <File Id="CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll"  Source="!(var.Path.Cefsharp.Commonx64)\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
</Component>
```

Hope this helps!

[Source - WIX docs (general)](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/component.html)

Comment: Thank you cosinepenguin for your answer. But the `$` Sign is working in all other XML files. Its just something about that path. If i am changing it to another variable everything is working fine except that it isn't finding the files obviously.

Comment: I will try it anyway at Monday. Looking forward to try it.

Comment: Interesting! In that case, wouldn't the source just be declared as `Source="$(Path.Cefsharp.Commonx64)\CefSharp.dll"`? Do you need the `var.`? When you try it on Monday do post your answer! I'm actually very curious!

Comment: Thank you sir it was `Path.Cefsharp.Commonx64`. I didnt checked it without var - happy that it is working.

Comment: Glad to hear it!